# Multichoice AlertDialog get selected values as Strings

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I get a `List` from server which I show as fields in `MultiChoice AlertDialog`. When the user checks a field I place it in another `List`. But I only get them as integers. How can I know which one was checked because I need the name of the item?

```
List<Integer> mSelectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void renderGenreList(List<Genre> genreList) {
        CharSequence[] genreChar = convertGenreList(genreList);
        genreDialog(genreChar);
    }

private CharSequence[] convertGenreList(List<Genre> genreList) {
    List<String> genreString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < genreList.size(); i++) {
        Genre genre = genreList.get(i);
        genreString.add(genre.getName());
    }
    return genreString.toArray(new CharSequence[genreString.size()]);
}

private void genreDialog(CharSequence[] genres) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder
            .setTitle(R.string.multiple_choice_title)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(genres, null, (dialog, which, isChecked) -> {
                if (isChecked) {
                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                    mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK_button, (dialog, which) -> {

                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.CANCEL_button, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());
    d = builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mSelectedItems list has the list of selected items position. So you can do below to get all items

```
for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItems.size(); i++) {
        Genre genre = genreList.get(mSelectedItems.get(i));
        // Here genre is one of the items selected and you can get all items in this loop
}
```

or **second** method is when you are adding values to `mSelectedItems` instead of adding which get the value and then add

replace -

```
mSelectedItems.add(which);
```

with

```
mSelectedItems.add(genreList.get(which));
```

then you will have `mSelectedItems` with list of selected items. Update the above for remove method as well.

the **third** way is to have instance of your dialog and get from there.

```
AlertDialog mAlert = builder.create();
// Display the alert dialog on interface
mAlert.show();

// get list of selected items
mAlert.getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
```